# Javascript Bookmarklet

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html, bookmarklet

I've coded a bookmarklet that opens a new window at a certain URL and sends some variables to a PHP using GET.
The problem is I need to have it load the same php and send the same variables but inside a div this time.

Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: I retagged the question by adding [ajax]. You might also want to consider a jQuery solution because jQuery supports AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Client Side - JavaScript & jQuery**

jQuery provides a GET operation using AJAX, for example `$.get("test.php");` See **[Ajax/Query.get docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype)** for more info: arguments, examples, etc.

The version to send GET variables is `$.get("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );` jQuery is an API layer on top of regular JavaScript that simply wraps the lower-level features and expresses them in a somewhat cross-browser compatible way.

**Server Side - PHP**

This [w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp) shows a sample of a PHP page picking up GET data from an AJAX call:

```
<?php
$name=$_GET["name"]; // John
$time=$_GET["time"]; // 2pm
```

Comment: Well the thing is I need this working inside of a bookmarklet. I can't include jquery on all pages i need to run this bookmarklet on. Any ideeas on this?

Comment: You can include jQuery script on all pages that have the bookmarklet if you use `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery132.js"></script>` or put this in the bookmarklet. Additionally you can inject JavaScript wherever a link would be used, for example `<A HREF="javascript:YourStuff();window.location=xyz">` for inside the bookmarklet.